# How can I display the current user logged in against the database?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, razor

I have created a website with a custom login to my database using SQL Server and would like to know how to display the text of the user logged in. Currently it is showing the users "Login" beside the word welcome but I would rather show the users actual name.
I am new to MVC3 and would like to know how to change the following line in the _LogOnPartial.cshtml to display a field from my database "AgentFirstName"

```
<text>Welcome <strong>@User.Identity.Name</strong>
```

Here is my AccountControler

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (DAL.MyWebsiteContextClass.userIsValid(model.AgentLogin, model.AgentPassword))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.AgentLogin, false);

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            }
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

Here is my agents model

```
public class Agents
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual string AgentFirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual string AgentLastName { get; set; }
    public virtual string AgentLogin { get; set; }
    public virtual string AgentPassword{ get; set; }
```

With a web config set like this

```
<add name="MyWebsiteContextClass"
     connectionString="Data Source=My-SQL\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=MyWebsite; Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=password"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

And this is in my context Class

```
public DbSet<Agents> AgentsPkg { get; set; }
```

Unfortunatley I do not know what else you might need to help me but if you need anything please ask and I will do what I can. 
Thanks for your help

Comment: I know this seems like it should be an easy first thing to try, but it's actually quite a bit more complicated than it seems.  To do it right, you have to learn a lot of underlying things.  First question is, do you already have a database that includes this information?  And how is it keyed? (how do you look it up?)

Comment: Yes I have a database with a table called Agents and a field called AgentFirstName. See the edit for code

Answer (score 1):

In your `Index` action of the `Home` controller, you could check if the user is authenticated ( using `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` ) and if this is the case, you could fetch the user information from your database using `User.Identity.Name` as the search key.

Let's say that you get an instance of `MyProject.Models.User` returned from the DB - you can then pass this instance to the `Index` view and then access the instance in the view.

In the view you need to declare the type of the model provided, in your case that migt be `@model MyProject.Models.User`. Then, you can access the `User` model instance in your view, and, e.g., print properties like first name and last name ( or whatever properties are available in your model ) - the model instance is accessed like this: `@Model.FirstName`.

To see an example of how to pass model instances to views and access the model instance properties in a strongly typed manner, a good example could be reading the section "*Strongly Typed Models and the @model Keyword*" in [this asp.net mvc3 tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/accessing-your-model%27s-data-from-a-controller).

Answer (score 0):

Based on your additional information... The solution to your problem is quite simple (at least A solution to your problem, it's not really ideal.. but an ideal solution is much more complex).

You simply query your Agents table based on AgentLogin and use User.Identity.Name as the criteria.  This allows you to get at the AgentFirstName and pass it to your model, where it can be displayed.

Comment: Can you please help me with some examples of how to do this on the LogonPartial.cshtml page?

Comment: @WillNZ - you will find that people are much more willing to help you figure out your own solution, and not all that willing to do your work for you.  Between Lasse and Myself we've given you all the information you should need.  If you can't figure it out, then you need to read a few tutorials because you have to learn more than we can teach you in this space.